# Less multiple classes and pseudo classes with the same style?

Tags: css, less

How can I simplify the css below in LESS code?

```
.push-nav > .active > a,
.push-nav > .active > a:hover,
.push-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background:#000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

My attempt:

```
.push-nav > .active > a {
    &:focus,
    &:hover {
        background:#000;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
.push-nav > .active > a:focus,
.push-nav > .active > a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

`.push-nav > .active > a` is missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: `&, &:focus, &:hover {..}`.

Comment: Just to reiterate @Harry's point on your [identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310268/less-multiple-different-classes-with-the-same-style), CSS is valid LESS so if you don't have a specific reason to refactor like hungerstar's solution your original code will do just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.push-nav > .active > a` is missing because you haven't included it.

The ampersand `&` represents the current selector.

Add:

```
.push-nav > .active > a {
    &,
    &:focus,
    &:hover {
        background: #00;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

In your code `& = .push-nav > .active > a`. So `&:focus = .push-nav > .active > a:focus`.