# LESS - multiple different classes with the same style?

Tags: css, less

How would you write this style below in LESS?

```
nav a:hover,
nav a:focus,
footer a:hover,
footer a:focus,
.fullscreen-container a:hover,
.fullscreen-container a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

My attempt:

```
.text-decoration-none () {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a {
    &:focus,
    &:focus {
        .text-decoration-none ();
    }
}

footer a {
    &:focus,
    &:focus {
        .text-decoration-none ();
    }
}

.fullscreen-container a {
    &:focus,
    &:focus {
        .text-decoration-none ();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
nav a:focus,
nav a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
footer a:focus,
footer a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.fullscreen-container a:focus,
.fullscreen-container a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Ideal result:

```
nav a:hover,
nav a:focus,
footer a:hover,
footer a:focus,
.fullscreen-container a:hover,
.fullscreen-container a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't overcomplicate things just because Less allows nesting. Your expected CSS output is actually the best way to write this even with Less. If you still want to proceed with the nesting approach, have a look at `extend`.

Comment: Extend will merge the each of the selectors into the `.text-decoration-none` reference. In this case there is no use for switching the mixin to another selector.

Comment: @BenSewards: I don't know if that comment was a response to my suggestion of extend. You can always avoid that mixin on the whole, mention the `text-decoration` inside one of the actual selectors and then extend it. (Also, I personally hate mixins which have nothing but one property, that's an overkill.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
nav, footer, .fullscreen-container {
  a {
    &:hover, &:focus {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea, avoid the mixin totally. I like it much better!

Comment: Though I'd even also [remove](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22nav%2C%20footer%2C%20.fullscreen-container%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20a%3Ahover%2C%20a%3Afocus%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20text-decoration%3A%20none%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D) the whole `a {}` thing (as it's obvious we'll be never about replacing it with some `b` by any means).

Answer (score 1):

```
.text-decoration-none () {
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a, footer a, .fullscreen-container a {
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        .text-decoration-none ();
    }
}
```